# Getting error: "Unauthenticated" with Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport

I'm trying to create a single page app with Laravel/Passport as the API backend. To sign up, I create my user as usual, then use Passport's ApiTokenCookieFactory to generate my JWT cookie like so:

```
// api_success is a response macro
    return $this->response->api_success('User successfully created')
       ->withCookie($this->cookie->make($newUser->getModel()->getKey(), $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN')));
```

You can assume that $this->cookie is the container's resolved cookie factory. This all works fine and I get a laravel_token cookie with the JWT.

When I go to make a request though, for example to api/users/me, I get this response:

```
{
    "error": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

I'm sending the CSRF token, I'm setting X-Requested-With to XMLHttpRequest, and the cookie is being sent along with the request.

The /api/users/me route has the api:auth middleware, so I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong. If anyone has any suggestions they'd be greatly appreciated <3

Comment: It's unclear, but have you checked this out? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

Comment: Yea so ideally I would use that middleware, but since it requires the request to be a GET, I'd have to refresh and then the cookie would be set, but since I want the cookie returned on my POST signup request, I essentially do what the middleware does by using the ApiTokenCookieFactory, and it works fine and I get my token set. The middleware doesn't look like it does anything else.

Comment: How are you sending the token?

Comment: I'm setting laravel_token as a cookie like the createFreshApiToken middleware does, and this token is sent with every request, and I think the auth:api middleware accepts this token?

Comment: are you sending the token as `Authorization` => `Bearer {{token}}`?

Comment: No, with the passport guard there are two options to supply the token, either the Authorization header with the Bearer, or the laravel_token cookie, I'm supplying it using the latter method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue I was having, if anyone gets here in the future, note that cookies are not encrypted by default!! Make sure to either add the encrypt cookies middleware to your route, or encrypt cookies manually. My god I was so happy when I figured this out. It turns out that the passport guard was trying to decrypt my unencrypted cookie and silently (!!) failing.